uncorrect bounding box of a mathjax formula in ubuntu/chromium
I want to know the dimensions of the bounding box of a formula rendered by mathjax version 4 beta 6.
On ubuntu, it works well on firefox, but it fail on chromium. Chromium gives me a value somewhere between the width before and after rendering.
I tried two methods : getBoundingClientRect and getComputedStyle. They give me the same(but wrong) result in chromium.
here is a minimal working example :
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script>
    MathJax = {
        tex: {
            inlineMath: [['$', '$'], ['\\(', '\\)']],
        },
        startup: {
            ready: () => {
                MathJax.startup.defaultReady();
                MathJax.startup.promise.then(() => {
                    //the following will give the width after rendering by mathjax
                    let mydiv = document.getElementById('mydiv');
                    let style = window.getComputedStyle(mydiv);
                    console.log(style.getPropertyValue('width'));
                    console.log(mydiv.getBoundingClientRect().width);
                });
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
    <script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@4.0.0-beta.6/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="mydiv" style="display:inline-block;border:1px solid red">
        $f(x)=x^2+2x+1$
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // The following lines will give the width before rendering by mathjax
        let mydiv = document.getElementById('mydiv');
        let style = window.getComputedStyle(mydiv);
        console.log(style.getPropertyValue('width'));
        console.log(mydiv.getBoundingClientRect().width);
    </script>
</body>
</html>

